# HTML/CSS: table font size different in mobile device

Tags: html, css, font-size, mobile-browser

I would like to have a simple website that works both on desktop and mobile browser, and encountered a weird (rookie) problem: when I have a table whose column texts are of different length, the font sizes rendered in mobile device are dramatically different. Any idea why this is happening and what is a quick and clean fix? Thanks in advance for your help!

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     body {
       font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
       font-size: medium;
     }
     table, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Short text. Short text</td>
        <td>Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Renders okay on desktop browser

[image: desktop]

Weird font size on mobile browser (chrome emulator)

[image: mobile]

Comment: What emulator are you referring to? This seems to be a bug in the emulator rather than anything else.

Comment: I was using Google Chrome mobile emulator, and nope, it's not a bug --- I saw the same rendering effect on my smart phone (and that's why I set out to fix it).

Comment: You’re correct, this oddity indeed happens in Chrome on Android (and the `meta` tag suggested in an answer fixes this).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to consider setting the **viewport** of your application. To make a mobile-friendly web application, you will need to set this in your headers. You can do so by adding a `<meta>` tag between your `<head>` tags. Here is an example:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

For a full description of what a viewport is and how it is used, you can visit the article [Configuring the Viewport](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) from Apple Developer as it was first introduced for Safari Mobile.

Comment: Thanks @Abel, but changing font-size does not solve my problem --- the emulator still has different font size on two columns.

Comment: @YingXiong take a look at my edited answer if it works for you

Comment: Yep, the `<meta>` tag corrects the rendering. If you could kindly add some more explanation on that tag, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: The font size settings are not relevant to the question.

Comment: I have just edited the answer and removed the unnecessary parts of it. Now it's just the plain solution.

Comment: This is MAGIC! 

Answer (score 11):

Eventually you might also need

```
text-size-adjust: none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

to make sure that text is not renderred bigger or smaller depending on the size of table cells. Especially in Safari on iOS I found this to be relevant.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. Thank you.

Comment: Same here. The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. +1. In particular, it seems it is "-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" the key. Pay attention to the "-", it is really "-webkit" not "webkit" ! Thank you Tom !

Answer (score -2):

try this

```css
 body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Reza, but setting the font-size does not solve my problem.